# SwiftUI swizzling disabled by default, phone auth not working

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I am building a screen with phone number login. I checked over and over again and the project is newly created, however, I am getting this log:

> 7.2.0 - [Firebase/Auth][I-AUT000015] The UIApplicationDelegate must handle remote notification for phone number authentication to work.
> If app delegate swizzling is disabled, remote notifications received by UIApplicationDelegate need to be forwarded to FIRAuth's canHandleNotificaton: method.

I did read in the documentation about swizzling and I don't know why it seems to be disabled, I did not disabled it. I have added GoogleServices-Info.plist into the app, I added in firebase panel the app apn auth key.

My entry point in the app looks like this:

```
@main
struct partidulverdeApp: App {
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    Auth.auth().canHandle(url.absoluteURL)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

My URL Types property has an entry with the RESERVED_CLIENT_ID

I am very desperate about this problem. Any idea is highly appreciated.

Edit1:

I did read the documentation and tried to handle notification with swizzling disabled, but I get the same error:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
        didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any],
        fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
      if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
        completionHandler(.noData)
        return
      }
      
    }
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        print("Your code here")
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct partidulverdeApp: App {
    
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
                .onOpenURL { url in
                    Auth.auth().canHandle(url.absoluteURL)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44320588/firebase-phone-auth-fails-to-pick-up-on-remote-notifications-registration). To add an `AppDelegate` to your app, see [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-an-appdelegate-to-a-swiftui-app)

Comment: @koen I edited my question. Long story short, I already tried that several times without any result. I have the same error. Do you have any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Ohh, now I see that I get: You've implemented -[<UIApplicationDelegate> application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:], but you still need to add "remote-notification" to the list of your supported UIBackgroundModes in your Info.plist. I will look how to solve it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's how to implement Phone Number Auth using the new SwiftUI 2 life cycle:

1. Create a Firebase project and set up PhoneNumber Auth
2. Add your iOS app to the Firebase project, download and add `GoogleService-Info.plist` to your project
3. In Xcode, select the application target and enable the following capabilities:

   - Push notifications
   - Background modes > Remote notifications
4. Create and register an APNS authentication key on the Apple developer portal
5. Upload the key to Firebase (under *Project Settings > Cloud messaging* in the Firebase Console)
6. Add the Firebase project's reversed client ID to your app's URL schemes
7. In your `Info.plist`, set `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to `NO`
8. Implement the `AppDelegate` as follows:

```swift
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    print("SwiftUI_2_Lifecycle_PhoneNumber_AuthApp application is starting up. ApplicationDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.")
    return true
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print("\(#function)")
    Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .sandbox)
  }
  
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification notification: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("\(#function)")
    if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(notification) {
      completionHandler(.noData)
      return
    }
  }
  
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
    print("\(#function)")
    if Auth.auth().canHandle(url) {
      return true
    }
    return false
  }
}

@main
struct SwiftUI_2_Lifecycle_PhoneNumber_AuthApp: App {
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .onOpenURL { url in
          print("Received URL: \(url)")
          Auth.auth().canHandle(url) // <- just for information purposes
        }
    }
  }
}
```

For further reading, I suggest these two articles I wrote:

- [Firebase and the new SwiftUI 2 Application Life Cycle](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-new-app-lifecycle-firebase/)
- [The Ultimate Guide to the SwiftUI 2 Application Life Cycle](https://peterfriese.dev/ultimate-guide-to-swiftui2-application-lifecycle/)

Comment: is it necessary to disable swizzling? I've gotten phone auth & FCMs to work with swizzling but I've noticed some weird side effects.

Comment: Can you elaborate how you got it working with swizzling (feel free to share a link to a GitHub repo / Gist so I can take a look), @bze12?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/benedelstein/8965d8b1eb9df9a63869cf493323dc39 I just set up the delegate similar to your answer, but never disabled swizzling. I'm able to receive cloud notifications and do phone auth without captcha, but the only weird thing is that my didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken is never called.

Comment: When I move FirebaseApp.configure() from app init to AppDelegate, Firebase Crashylitics is not working anymore (at least in my app).

Comment: @emreoktem did you find any fix for the issue ?